# cocos2dx animations lag whenever admob receives ad

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I'm running smooth CCScaleTo actions in my cocos2dx(v2.0.4) game scene. After adding admob(v6.2.1) to cocos2dx's openGLView, the actions lag whenever admob receives a new ad.

I test two cases:

1. Remove the ad view from view hierarchy. The animations lag when admob `loadRequst:`
2. Comment out the admob `loadRequest:` and add the ad view back to view hierarchy. The animations lag within the first few seconds game scene load.

It seems related to UIKit & cocos2dx integration issue.

Any idea to workaround?

Comment: You already narrowed it down to AdMob receiving an ad. That sounds reasonable. AdMob is not designed for realtime animations, so it may take a large chunk of time in order to retrieve and display the ad and there may be nothing you can do. You could however try to make AdMob fetch the ad in a background thread, if possible.

Comment: The fps remain 60. It seems like admob internal animation (which I can't disable )blocking cocos2dx main thread. Admob already fetch aync，I think. The lag only happens when ad switch.

Answer (score 0):

The trick that comes to mind is: don't let AdMob handle its own display (since it will insist on doing that animation). Instead, build the Adview, and only add it to your view hierarchy AFTER the normal animation would have finished, using i.e. `dispatch_after`.

Ideally you'd wrap the `UIView` in a `cocos2d` object so that `CCDirector` can do the animations instead of `UIKit`. That might be more work than it's worth, but it would definitely keep the animation thread from blocking.